Empty _fbc parameter, what to pass?
I'm trying to improve my event score in meta business panel.
Pixel is loaded from the GTM.
I am working on Prestashop 1.7.8.5 and I'm not using facebook module.
I'm around 3 out of 10 points in every event.
They all share the same warning like "PageView events send empty fbc parameter".
What should I pass to GTM/pixel when user does not have any _fbc id in the url and in cookies?
